# CEF 3; "libcef.dll" not found when starting render process (but works fine when running under single process)

Tags: c++, multithreading, chromium-embedded

I've been having a look at CEF lately. Oddly, I can't run any CEF applications in their default mode as I keep getting an error message:

> "The program can't start because libcef.dll is missing from your
>   computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem".

The log file contains one error message only

> [0127/102612:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(113)] Failed to
>   launch GPU process.

This happens in any scenario; no matter whether debug/release build, and no matter whether starting the cefsimple or cefclient example apps.
To rule out any particular compilation issues, I've even downloaded the precompiled example app - but am facing the very same error there.

I'm not trying to do anything fance there; all DLLs and other required files are in the root folder, the msvc++ runtime is installed.

Having said that, forcing CEF to run in a single process seems to fix the issue, e.g. starting with

> cefclient.exe --single-process

works fine.

So something in a multi-process scenario seems to prevent the render process from resolving its dependencies correctly. I am running this in a relatively restricted IT environment, but given all files are present in the local directory, I'm not really sure what could possibly interfere there.

Anybody has any ideas what could be causing this issue in the default (multi-process) scenario?

Comment: You say multithreaded when it's actually multi process, for whatever reason the sub processes aren't starting.

Comment: Whoops. My bad, sorry - edited/fixed the title & problem description

Comment: Try process monitor from Microsoft, see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks - great suggestion in principle. However, can't run procmon on the machine unfortunately due to a lack of admin rights. I'll try to figure out if any way to monitor dll loading directly via the Visual Studio debugger, though given its detached from the new process by default, might be tricky

Comment: Hmm, might be worth asking someone from your it department to run assist? In the mean time, you can up the log level, get more diagnostic messaging, standard Chrome command line args should work. https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/debugging-on-windows

Comment: There is also the renderer startup dialog that is useful for hooking the debugger, though your process might not even be spawning.